# How to add li with <a> tag?

Tags: jquery

I have a code like this

```
<div id="content">
 <ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

I would like to use jQuery to add li depending on a service response.

In my js, i am doing the following

```
function(response){
 for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++) {
   var url =response[i].href;
   var label=response[i].title;
   $("#content ul").append('<li><a href="#"><span class="tab">Test</span></a></li>');
 }}
```

I can see Test thrice as li, so append is working fine, but i want to provide url and label above as anchor tag elements.
So, instead of Test, i should see label value and for href ,it should point to url values,retrieved from the response.

Also,  on entering of this method, I need to remove all previously li appended to $('#content ul')
Any pointer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine for you

```
function(response){
    $('#content ul').empty();
    for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var url =response[i].href;
        var label=response[i].title;
        $('#content ul').append('<li><a href="' + response[i].href + '"><span class="tab">' + response[i].title + '</span></a></li>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks James, I forgot to ask, on entering of this method, I need to remove all previously li appended to  $('#content ul').Any pointer?

Comment: updated with a cheeky bit of jQuery.empty() should clear the ul element completely! :) http://api.jquery.com/empty/